# how do I make my nodejs server available remotely?

Tags: networking, remote

I have a nodejs server running on my machine. I managed to make it accessible remotely with an ngrok tunnel, but I would like to avoid using tunnels. I prefer to use other methods if possible. I think you can use the method with public IP!?
I have configured the router for port forwarding and the requests made remotely arrive at my machine on port 5001 which is the one that listens to the nodejs server. But the server ignores these requests. Why?  Is there something else?

**serverHTTPS.js**

```
https.createServer({ key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert') }, app)
    .listen(VAR.SERVER_PORT, () => {
        console.log(`server listening on ${VAR.SERVER_PORT}`);
    }
)
```

**UPDATE:**
if the server listens in HTTP mode I can communicate remotely but when I enter in HTTPS mode I can no longer communicate in remote. However with wireshark I can see the packets addressed to port 5001 of the machine hosting the server. If the request is sent to localhost the server communicates with the client.

**UPDATE2**
I did further tests, I believe it is a problem of acceptance of the self signed certificate, here are the results:

**1)** From app to rest on smartphone, both HTTP and HTTPS works remotely but to get an answer with HTTPS I had to enable 'SSL Check' on the same android app;

**2)** The PC and smartphone browsers are able to communicate with the server and obtain the data from the API in HTTPS, only after I accept the self-signed unsafe certificate. (I insert in the address bar for example: 'https: // myip: 5001 / getCars')

**3)** The preview of the angular app on stackblitz is able to communicate with the server and access the API only after I have performed step 2 (acceptance of the unsafe certificate)

**4)** The angular app on the same machine that hosts the server, is able to communicate with the nodejs server only after carrying out point 2 (acceptance of the certificate but this time the certificate of localhost)
*All this tests are made in firefox*

**At this point my question changes, how do I get the certificate accepted by the angular app, because when I run the app no ​​acceptance of the self signed certificate is asked, Thank you guys**

Comment: AFAIK if the requests are routed via port forwarding on the correct machine and port it should actually work. Please be sure that this is really the case. Are there any other ports involved?

Comment: OK. I checked better, I have 2 different behaviors, if the request is made on my machine (where the server is hosted), the packets appear to arrive on port 5001 but if the request is made by smartphone the packets do not arrive. This I saw with wireshark. However the server ignores requests that arrive. So there are 2 problems, 1) the server ignores requests reaching port 5001; 2) requests from the smartphone or any other remote device do not arrive at port 5001 of my machine.

Comment: sorry, but in the smartphone I had not set the port. The requests also arrive from the smartphone on my machine at port 5001

Comment: You must forward traffic from your external IP on a specific port (likely 5001) to your internal IP on port 5001. Almost all consumer routers support this feature. It will be in your router's configuration page.

Comment: @SamForbis I configured it on the router for forwarding. Packages arrive on my machine! The server ignores requests

Comment: @canerandagio Are you really sure that you correctly set up your port forwarding for in/outbound as well as UDP/TCP traffic? There might be something fishy with the router configuration. I also have a node.js testserver on my RPi which does work through port forwarding if I remember correctly.

I assume that because actually it makes no difference what service you use and combine with port forwarding as long as the port forwarding is set up correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a port conflict with some other service? Try changing the port to something else. If you generally have issues with the port 5001 that might be the culprit.

Comment: @thex I forwarded both TCP and UDP. The packets of request arrive on my machine at 5001 port so is not a router configuration issue. I tried others ports with the same results. In localhost it works.

Comment: @canerandagio If it is no routing issue it can only be an issue on your machine and the hosting of your service. Try accessing via local network without passing through router. Based on the information you provided, it is a hosting issue and should also not work on LAN. I can't think of something else that might result in the described behaviour.

Comment: Please also provide OS your node.js server runs on.

Comment: @thex In localhost works. I run debian.

Comment: HTTP works, HTTPS doesen't work

Comment: Not sure if this has been covered but have you checked what IP it is bound to? for example in windows you can bind to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.x.y and these all have very different effects. You'd want 0.0.0.0  And i'm sure linux has a corresponding thing Linux's netstat command can show you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408958/how-to-prevent-new-isolated-virtual-interface-from-listening-to-0-0-0-0

Comment: @canerandagio I do understand that localhost works, but that was not the question. Does it work in local LAN. Without passing the request through the router?

Comment: @barlop This is also the thing I assumed! Because of that I was asking if the Node.js server is reachable within LAN. Because it is on localhost and is not through router (port forwarding). If you have a configuration issue with your server you should also not be able to access the server via LAN (and this is what I assume). So obviously you can access via localhost but you can't over network at all.

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply and interest. I have updated my ask with new investigations, UPDATE2, it seems to be a self signed certificate issue